# How to pivot multiple columns (int and date)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.children_bd (
    birthday_id int,
    child_birthday_id int,
    notification_parents date,
    notification_grandparents date,
    invitation_parents_id int,
    invitation_grandparents_id int
);

INSERT INTO dbo.children_bd
VALUES (1,9, '02-01-2021','07-01-2021', 4, 5);
```

Here is my code:

```
select birthday_id, child_birthday_id, tm, rm
from (
    select p.birthday_id, p.child_birthday_id, p.notification_parents,
p.notification_grandparents, p.invitation_parents_id, p.invitation_grandparents_id
    from dbo.children_bd p
) t
UNPIVOT
(tm for id in (invitation_parents_id, invitation_grandparents_id)) pvt1
UNPIVOT
(rm for rid in (notification_parents, notification_grandparents)) pvt2
```

I receive this:

```
+------------+-------------------+-----+-------------+
|birthday_id | child_birthday_id | tm  |  rm         |
+------------+------------------ +-----+-------------+
|  1         |        9          |  4  | 2021-02-01  |
|  1         |        9          |  4  | 2021-07-01  |
|  1         |        9          |  5  | 2021-02-01  |
|  1         |        9          |  5  | 2021-07-01  |
+-------+----------+-------------+-----+--------------
```

but I would like to receive this:

```
+------------+-------------------+-----+-------------+
|birthday_id | child_birthday_id | tm  |  rm         |
+------------+------------------ +-----+-------------+
|  1         |        9          |  4  | 2021-02-01  |
|  1         |        9          |  5  | 2021-07-01  |
+-------+----------+-------------+-----+--------------
```

Comment: I receive this: https://prnt.sc/214tz04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to unpivot multiple values you can use [`CROSS APPLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-apply) along with a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT c.birthday_id,
       c.child_birthday_id,
       upvt.Type,
       upvt.NotificationDate,
       upvt.InvitationID
FROM   dbo.children_bd AS c
       CROSS APPLY 
       (VALUES 
           ('Parents', c.notification_parents, c.invitation_parents_id),
           ('Grandparents', c.notification_grandparents, c.invitation_grandparents_id)
        ) AS upvt (Type, NotificationDate, InvitationID);
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d556ce543b71b58de3329e3395da43d8)**